# How to disable refresh interval in elastic search, does it require restart of node/cluster after updating configuration?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-5

How to disable the refresh interval in elastic search.

Once we disable refresh interval, does it require restart of node or cluster ?

Is the below method is correct way of disabling refresh interval ? Just checking because, I'm doing this on production server which has heavy load and data is in billion ( bit worried because of this).

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index" : {
    "refresh_interval" : "-1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not require restarting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's the correct way of disabling `refresh_interval`.

And no, you needn't restart your Cluster because this is a `dynamic` setting as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk).

Note that you can also disable `refresh_interval` on multiple indices by using `my-index-*`.